# AngularJs ng-view to change value of parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am facing a problem respected to ng-view. 
here is the code.

```
<header ng-controller="headCtrl" ng-show="landing.ifLandind">            
</header>

<div ng-view></div>
```

There are two controller one "headCtrl" and other loads when ng-view is loads. I want to change the "landing.ifLandind" from the controller loads in ng-view. How can i refer it in second controller that it will change the value of "landing.ifLandind" in the "headCtrl". Thanks in  advance for help

Comment: you can try to use [controller as](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) syntax, though if the 2 controllers are siblings and not parent-child, then you might consiter `$parent` or  `$rootScope` or using a custom service to share the state

Comment: Thanks. For help. was very helpful respected.

Answer (score 2):

why you don't **use a service** for control header?

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

You can inject the service in all controllers that need manipulate header.

For example:

```
angular.module('myModule').factory('serviceHeader', function() {
 var modelHeader = {
    hidden: false,
    hide: function() {
      this.hidden = true;
    },
    show: function() {
      this.hidden = false;
    },
    toggle: function() {
      this.hidden = !this.hidden;
    }
 };
 // factory function body that constructs shinyNewServiceInstance
 return modelHeader;
});


angular.module('myModule').controller('FooController' ['serviceHeader', function(serviceHeader) {
  ...
  serviceHeader.hide(); //hide header
  ...
}]);


angular.module('myModule').controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', 'serviceHeader', function($scope, serviceHeader) {
  $scope.headerHelper = serviceHeader;
}]);



<header ng-controller="HeaderController" ng-show="!headerHelper.hidden">            
</header>

<div ng-view></div>
```

**Or you can use $watch**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

hope this helps.

regards

Answer (score 0):

You could inject $rootScope into both the controllers(headCtrl and ng-view's controller). Then in ng-veiw's controller add

```
$rootScope.$emit('controllerLoaded', <value>) //<value> is some value you wish to send
```

And in headCtrl add

```
$rootScope.$on('controllerLoaded', function(value) {  
    $scope.landing.ifLandind = ... //add whatever change you want to make
})

So whenever a controller loads event "controllerLoaded" gets emitted and received in headCtrl.
```